# Does the browser resemble what it will look like on a small mobile device? After resizing the browser?

Tags: css

If I resize the browser window the inner divs don't remain consistent with the wrapper div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
                border:2px solid red;
    }

    .pc {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width:32%;
        border:2px solid blue;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" >
        <div class="pc" >
            <h2>Heading 1</h2>
            <p>commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehende </p>
        </div>          

        <div class="pc" >
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <p>cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia mollit</p>
        </div>

        <div class="pc" >
            <h2>Heading 3</h2>
            <p>cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deser</p>
        </div>      
</div>
```

Here are sample pics of what happens when I resize browser window Chrome and Firefox, I haven't tried other browsers. The border gap in the border width is what I am referring to. I'm not looking for another solution like centering but more curious as to why this happens.

[image]

[image]

Comment: because you are using 32% + 2px ... so if the container has 1000px you will have 324px for each and the gap will be = 28px. If the container is only 100px you will have 36px for each and there is no gap !. so imagine a grow from 0 to a bigger value. That's it !

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

Because you have the width of your `.pc` divs to 32%, and 32 + 32 + 32 = 96. So you are seeing the extra 4% gap on the right, which will be wider on larger screens and very thin on smaller screens.

Also, you are not using `box-sizing: border-box;` so your border widths are not calculated into your overall width. So the width of 1 `.pc` is actually 32% + 2px right border + 2px left border.

Comment: and with the border in the calculation also as he's not using `box-sizing:border-box` ;)

Comment: I can understand very thin but they end up touching

Comment: @ticktock check my comment above, they endup touching because of the border. It's a simple calculation

Comment: @zgood, if I make the browser even smaller the third pc div flows underneath the other two, does that mean it will also do the same on a smaller screen. Is what I am seeing on my pc screen a resemblance of a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

By default, elements that are `inline-block` will not auto-fill to the height of their container.

Instead, you can set the wrapper to `display: flex`:

```
#wrapper {
  border:2px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
```

Or, you can set each `.pc` element to `display:table-cell`:

```
.pc {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:32%;
  border:2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering about the width, if you can see where the border is in the first pic and where it is in the second pic. I'm just curious to know why the loss of so many pixels. Not really trying to solve a design problem

Comment: ah, for width, the widths for 3 elements are set to 32%, so 3 * 32% = 96% with a 4% gap